# Javascript multiple assignment

Tags: javascript

What means that code?

```
function myConnectController($state, $my, myService, apiJobs, apiMy) {
  var ctrl = this, mySequenceDataService; // this statement
  ...
  function init() {
    mySequenceDataService = $my.mySequenceDataServiceFactory.createInstance({
  ...
  });}
  ...
}
```

Is that some kind of inheritance?

Comment: That `var` declaration declares two variables: one called "ctrl" and one called "mySequenceDataService".

Comment: @Pointy then what's value of `mySequenceDataService` variable?

Comment: at that point is has no value. the value is set on this line     mySequenceDataService = $my.mySequenceDataServiceFactory.createInstance({
  ...
  });}

Comment: It's `undefined` because it is not initialized (at least not in the code you posted).

Answer (score 2):

`var` within a function declares a (local) variable.

You can "chain" assignments after one `var` keyword by comma seperating them.

```
var ctrl = this, mySequenceDataService;
               ^// comma seperating variables
```

In this example mySequenceDataService is assigned `undefined`, but is local and will not try to look in other scopes or the global scope for a variable named like that, nor assign the value(which happens in your init method) to a global scope variable.

you can also do this:

```
 var foo = 'hello', baz = 'world', bal = 'universe';
```